# Laravel after moved project from localhost to cpanel need to change the public_path to upload files

Tags: php, laravel

I have project working fine on localhost and can upload images with no issues but now I moved the project to be online on capnel the problem is when I upload image it goes to public folder while I want it to be upload to main root: example: site.com/images/file.jpg but now the upload file goes to site.com/public/images/file.jpg so how can I avoid uploading to public folder as I want to upload to images folder directly.. I tried to modify filesystems in config but not working

```
 'disks' => [

   'local' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => public_path('/images'),
    ],

    'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/uploads',
      'visibility' => 'public',
   ],
```

Comment: php artisan config:cache

Comment: Their is a thread for that
 https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-file-storage?page=1
you can find your answer here

Comment: I think you didn't get what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `root` variable from:

```
  'root' => public_path('/images'),
```

to

```
  'root' => '/images',
```